# Create a TRIGGER to create a TRIGGER when a table is created

Tags: mysql, triggers, ddl-trigger

I am interested in creating a `TRIGGER` that creates a `TRIGGER` when a table is created.

Poking around in mysql databases, I noticed that the tables for a schema are returned with:

`select TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA from information_schema.TABLES;`

Is the following a proper method to create a `TRIGGER`, to create a `TRIGGER` bound to a different schema?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `information_schema`.`argus_table_creation`
    AFTER INSERT on `TABLES`
    BEGIN
        --trigger here
        CREATE TRIGGER `argus`.`after_argus_insert` --create trigger bound to DB 'argus', titled 'after_insert'
        AFTER INSERT ON `argus_table_2013_06_27` FOR EACH ROW -- perform the trigger, `after insert`, on the `argus_table_2013_06_27` table, `for each row` that is inserted.
        BEGIN
                INSERT INTO argus.historic_argus_saddrdaddr(saddr, daddr)
                (
                SELECT saddr, daddr
                FROM (SELECT NEW.saddr, NEW.daddr) as derived
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT saddr, daddr FROM argus.historic_argus_saddrdaddr where historic_argus_saddrdaddr.saddr = derived.saddr and historic_argus_saddrdaddr.daddr = derived.daddr)
                );
        END//
    END//
DELIMITER;
```

#### Reasoning:

I use a client application ([rasqlinsert](http://qosient.com/argus/man/man1/rasqlinsert.1.pdf)) that automatically creates new tables that match a given naming scheme (where you can utilize strftime(f)).  I need to create a trigger on these auto-generated tables as they are generated.  This is why I am looking for a solution.

#### Another possible solution

Is it possible to advise the developer of the software to use a command similar to `CREATE TABLE n LIKE x`, but have it copy triggers?

P.S.
Contacted dev.  Will roll change in with `3.0.7.11` to accept arbitrary SQL to perform along with creation of new DB.  Expects code to hit dev repo by Monday.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A schema for a database is a static affair. You create the tables/triggers etc just the once for the application. No need to create triggers/tables on the fly.

Comment: I've updated the original question with `reasoning`.

Comment: Seems to me that somebody cannot use the fully functionality of a RDBMS to include make it 3NF (that includes time)

Comment: +1 for being creative.

Comment: I would make it part of my build process, using liquibase to check if triggers exist and create one if not.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  The dev is adding logic to handle arbitrary post `CREATE TABLE` tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set triggers on tables in the `information_schema` database.

---

*Can you please provide a citation? – mbrownnyc*

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html

> ## MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual
>
> **Chapter 20. INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables**
>
> **Usage Notes for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA Database**
>
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a database within each MySQL instance, the place that stores information about all the other databases that the MySQL server maintains. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database contains several read-only tables. They are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files associated with them, and **you cannot set triggers on them**.

Comment: I've updated the original question with some `reasoning`.  Is there another solution to this challenge?

Comment: Can you please provide a citation?